# $K$-linear functional $K^n \to K$ acting on $K$-vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $K$ be a field, and let $f : K^n \to K$ be any $K$-linear functional. Suppose $V$ is a $K$-vector space. Then $f$ “extends” to a $K$-linear map $f_V : V^n \to V$ in the following way:

If $f$ sends $(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ to $a_1 x_1 + \dots + a_n x_n$, let $f_V(v_1, \dots, v_n) = a_1 v_1 + \dots + a_n v_n$.

I'm trying to get a feel for how natural this extension is. Does it have a name? Does it have a category-theoretic interpretation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just the functor $(V \otimes_K -)$ applied to $f$. Note that $V \otimes_K K^n \cong V^n$, and $V \otimes_K f = 1_V \otimes_K f$, so $$f_V:V^n \cong V \otimes_K K^n \xrightarrow{1_V \otimes_K f}V \otimes_K K \cong V$$
is given as follows: represent $(v_1,\ldots,v_n) \in V^n$ by $\sum_i v_i \otimes e_i \in V \otimes_K K^n$, where $(e_i)$ is the standard basis of $K^n$; apply $1_V \otimes_K f$ to get $\sum_i v_i \otimes a_i$; then this represents $\sum_i a_iv_i \in V$.